# Is there a way to fake-codesign OS X apps, e.g. in order to use iTunesLibrary.framework?

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

As the title states: I'd like to play around with iTunesLibrary.framework, without any intent to release the code. Is there a way to modify my system to accept code signing with a self-signed cert, or disable the code signing requirement for iTunesLibrary.framework?

I remember fake-codesigning an executable to make it run on my jailbroken iPhone, but I'm not quite sure on how to apply this to OS X, since it is not "jailbroken" per se. Is disabling Gatekeeper enough to allow for self-signed code to run? Haven't had too much luck yet, but maybe I'm doing the code signing part wrong...

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.